# SoundCloud player from stream unable to get duration

Tags: javascript, soundcloud

I am currently trying to make a progress bar for my own custom player. For some reason, getDuration() is returning a value whether it is treated like the widget's getDuration with a callback function or as if it just pulling a value.

(duration is declared globally which after testing doesn't seem to make a difference in the problem)

```
duration = player.getDuration();
var minutes = (duration / 1000) / 60;
var strMin = "" + Math.floor(minutes);
var strSec = "" + Math.floor((minutes - Math.floor(minutes)) * 60);
var pad = "00";
var text = strMin + ":" + pad.substring(0, pad.length - strSec.length) + strSec;
$('#bufferText').html(text);
```

This is how the API says it would be handled based on description and it is how the other methods from the class work but passing in a callback function also does not work.

Comment: Can you clarify the question a little more? In one sentence you say it _is_ returning a value, but the question title says you are not getting a value. You also mention a callback function, which is not show in your sample code.

Comment: The issue has been resolved which I self-commented but am unable to set as the accepted answer yet based on stackoverflow's website rules.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that isn't thinking straight like I was, the player doesn't pull any of the information until buffering/playback starts. Putting the code excerpt inside of a listener for the `play-start` event of the player fixed the issue.